# Help with bluetooth!

Tags: bluetooth

I made a video because I could not explain it with just typing, So if anyone could help me with this, I'd be grateful and very happy. Thanks in advance.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22cyVZHTb54

Comment: Did you try connecting a bluetooth dongle to your machine, or turn the bluetooth on if it already has one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the programs you use to start the bluetooth, is the drivers. Find out the hardware for your bluetooth and google if you have to install some additional drivers for it. Good luck